# Why does ghc warn that ^2 requires "defaulting the constraint to type 'Integer'?

Tags: haskell, types

If I compile the following source file with `ghc -Wall`:

```
main = putStr . show $ squareOfSum 5

squareOfSum :: Integral a => a -> a
squareOfSum n = (^2) $ sum [1..n]
```

I get:

```
powerTypes.hs:4:18: warning: [-Wtype-defaults]
    • Defaulting the following constraints to type ‘Integer’
        (Integral b0) arising from a use of ‘^’ at powerTypes.hs:4:18-19
        (Num b0) arising from the literal ‘2’ at powerTypes.hs:4:19
    • In the expression: (^ 2)
      In the expression: (^ 2) $ sum [1 .. n]
      In an equation for ‘squareOfSum’:
          squareOfSum n = (^ 2) $ sum [1 .. n]
  |
4 | squareOfSum n = (^2) $ sum [1..n]
  |                  ^^
```

I understand that the type of (^) is:

```
Prelude> :t (^)
(^) :: (Integral b, Num a) => a -> b -> a
```

which means it works for any `a^b` provided `a` is a `Num` and `b` is an `Integral`. I also understand the type hierarchy to be:

```
Num --> Integral --> Int or Integer
```

where `-->` denotes "includes" and the first two are typeclasses while the last two are types.

Why does `ghc` not conclusively infer that `2` is an `Int`, instead of "defaulting the constraints to Integer". Why is `ghc` defaulting anything? Is replacing `2` with `2 :: Int` a good way to resolve this warning?

Comment: IMO `(^)` should better have simply type `Num a => a -> Int -> a`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I'm pretty sure I disagree. Most of the other places `Int` is used instead of a typeclass-polymorphic type, like `take` and `length`, can be defended by observing that lists (or whatever container type) big enough to make an index overflow can't fit in memory in the first place. But very large exponentiation is a completely sensible thing to do in small amounts of both memory and time; e.g. if you want to do 40-bit-secure [ElGamal encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_encryption) on elliptic curves, you do exponentiation by an ~80-bit number.

Comment: @DanielWagner sure, but then you probably wouldn't use `^` anyway, but something dedicated. Most use cases of exponentiation work on numbers, not a finite field, and then exponentiation _is_ bound to the same issues as `take` and `length`. In fact, I suspect a majority of uses are indeed trivial stuff like squaring as asked about here, and there defaulting to `Integer` is rather hilarious..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Haskell, numeric literals have a *polymorphic* type

```
2 :: Num a => a
```

This means that the expression `2` can be used to generate a value in any numeric type. For instance, all these expression type-check:

```
2 :: Int
2 :: Integer
2 :: Float
2 :: Double
2 :: MyCustomTypeForWhichIDefinedANumInstance
```

Technically, each time we use `2` we would have to write `2 :: T` to choose the actual numeric type `T` we want. Fortunately, this is often not needed since type inference can frequently deduce `T` from the context. E.g.,

```
foo :: Int -> Int
foo x = x + 2
```

Here, `x` is an `Int` because of the type annotation, and `+` requires both operands to have the same type, hence Haskell infers `2 :: Int`. Technically, this is because `(+)` has type

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

Sometimes, however, type inference can not deduce `T` from the context. Consider this example involving a custom type class:

```
class C a where bar :: a -> String

instance C Int     where bar x = "Int: " ++ show x
instance C Integer where bar x = "Integer: " ++ show x

test :: String
test = bar 2
```

What is the value of `test`? Well, if `2` is an `Int`, then we have `test = "Int: 2"`. If it is an `Integer`, then we have `test = "Integer: 2"`. If it's another numeric type `T`, we can not find an instance for `C T`.

This code is inherently ambiguous. In such a case, Haskell mandates that numeric types that can not be deduced are *defaulted* to `Integer` (the programmer can change this default to another type, but it's not relevant now). Hence we have `test = "Integer: 2"`.

While this mechanism makes our code type check, it might cause an unintended result: for all we know, the programmer might have wanted `2 :: Int` instead. Because of this, GHC chooses the default, but warns about it.

In your code, `(^)` can work with any `Integral` type for the exponent. But, in principle, `x ^ (2::Int)` and `x ^ (2::Integer)` could lead to different results. We know this is not the case since we know the semantics of `(^)`, but for the compiler `(^)` is only a random function with that type, which could behave differently on `Int` and `Integer`. Consider, e.g.,

```
a ^ n = if n + 3000000000 < 0 then 0 else 1
```

When `n = 2`, if we use `n :: Int` the `if` guard could be true on a 32 bit system. This is not the case when using `n :: Integer` which never overflows.

The standard solution, in these cases, is to resolve the warning using something like `x ^ (2 :: Int)`.

Comment: Superb. Conclusive explanation end to end. On reflection then, having both a default, and a warning that the default has been applied, feels a bit contradictory since everything is working as it should. Particularly since I feel as the *user* of a function that accepts `Integral` I shouldn't be concerned whether I'm supplying an `Int` or an `Integer`. But I'm still learning and this is all great guidance, thank you.